# Invalid INDX entries for $I30 on NTFS harddisk

Tags: hex, reverse-engineering, ntfs

While parsing my NTFS formatted hard disk, I found some invalid entries of INDX while Windows is still able to list all the root directory contents!

The structure of the Index Record in *NTFS 3.1* is clear ([NTFS doc](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf)):

```
Offset      Description
-------------------------------------
0x00        MFT Reference of the file
0x08        Size of the index entry
0x0A        Offset to the filename
...
0x52        Filename
...
```

However, I found some entries where their size is faulty as well as their MFT Reference (which is a bunch of zeros)!

I enclose a screenshot that shows a part of INDX along side with their text representations where each line is of width `0x20`. I highlighted the faulty part.

[image: The invalid entries of INDX]

The figure shows that entries were parsed rationally until the last correct entry at `0x0628`:

- MFT Reference (8 bytes): `66 30 00 00 00 00 01 00`
- Size of entry (2 bytes): `70 00`
  So the entry ends at `0x0697`.

Thereafter, things got weird! Entries at `0x0698`:

- MFT Reference (8 bytes): `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` Seems invalid
- Size of entry (2 bytes): `10 00` Of course invalid because the size is less than the entry structure minimum size that includes the filename at `0x52` for instance.

For me, it seems that "Buziol Games" was a deleted folder on the root directory of the harddisk, I am not sure. Anyway, Windows explorer is not facing troubles on listing the contents.

Do anybody understand how does it work? How do Windows continue parsing?

**EDIT**: In addition, please find the hex dump as a pure text on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kksNZQ5t)

Comment: Could you show the code you are using for parsing? Have you taken **fixup values** into account? Also, please post a hex dump of the INDX record in text format (or link to a Pastebin).

Comment: As you know @AndreaLazzarotto , fixups is on the beginning of sectors, while index starts at the beginning of cluster (and thus at the beginning of a sector). So, the address 0x0698 is not the end of any sector. Please note that in my case the sector size is 0x200 and the cluster size is 8 sectors. Anyway, thank you for this gesture. By the way, I am not talking here about the code, the values theirselves are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As files get renamed, added, and deleted, INDX records end up containing unzeroized slack space at their end. Each INDX "page" is always 4096 bytes long, and as files get deleted the B+ tree nodes get shifted, leaving old, abandoned nodes at the end of INDX pages. This is very useful for forensics.

The "Buziol Games" entry appears to be a perfectly valid INDX record. Why do you think it was deleted?

Note that the INDX header (right where the "INDX" string is) can tell you how many entries there are in the page - check out offset 0x1c (size of index entries) vs offset 0x20 (allocated size of index entries). And note that these are relative to offset 0x18.

So looking at your pastebin output, in offset 0x1c we find the value 0x690 which means that the last entry ends at 0x18 + 0x690 = 0x6A8. The entry you see at offset 0x698 seems to be a kind of "null" entry, as per https://0cch.com/ntfsdoc/concepts/index_record.html:

`last entry has a size of 0x10 (just large enough
    for the flags (and a mft ref of zero))`

Note thst its size is 0x10 which means it ends at 0x6A8, as expected.

See also https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2012/10/incident-response-ntfs-indx-buffers-part-4-br-internal.html.

A good description of NTFS can be found at http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf.

Comment: Thank you dear. Replying to your question **"Why do you think it was deleted?"**: Because it is not visible by Windows Explorer. Anyway, maybe I am wrong (Maybe it was hidden) but it is not worth to focus on it so much since it is not what I am puzzled for. I am perplexed because I see some related and fundamental stuff outside the index entry (after 0x6A8) in which I wonder how to access noting that there exists only **one datarun** which points to this INDX!. Would you please explain how can I parse "Program Files" folder for instance. Shortly, how to continue parsing after 0x6A8?

Comment: "How to continue parsing after 0x6A8" - you don't. The INDX record ends at 0x6A8. All the stuff you see afterwards is so-called "slack space". It was used once but isn't used right now. Not sure I understood what you meant by parsing "Program Files" - do you want to recursively enumerate all files in your disk? If so, then starting from the current INDX record you'll need to take the MFT entry for the file you want to process (e.g. "Program Files"), find its INDX record(s) and enumerate them. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I meant, if I want to list the root directory contents, I found that it contains just part of them. where are the others? Repeating myself, please note that there exists only one datarun

Comment: You said that there exists only one datarun pointing to the INDX, but there could be multiple INDX pages. How did you find this INDX page? You should start with the MFT entry for the root folder and continue from there.

Comment: Great! It seems that you are pointing towards the correct direction. How to find those multiple INDX pages? How are they related? Mentioned? I found this INDX page through: . (Dot MFT entry) -> INDEX_ALLOCATION (Datarun).

Comment: The $INDEX_ALLOCATION attribute should point you to all INDX clusters. See for example https://medium.com/@mbromileyDFIR/ntfs-part-5-13e20588af59, where it shows an $INDEX_ALLOCATION attribute that points to multiple clusters. Do you not see this on your root folder?